# Proving A = {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4,...}. Having trouble in showing onto.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, infinity, proof-explanation

Prove the set `A = {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4,...}` is infinite.

I did by showing `A` is equivalent to `N`, the set of natural numbers. So we have to show there exists a bijective function between `A` and `N`. Lets take:

`F: N -> A => F(x) = 1/x`

Clearly, this is one to one since: `F(x) = F(y) => 1/x = 1/y => x = y`

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the onto part.

We can make `y` the subject to get `1/x` and this gives: `F(1/x) = 1/(1/x) = x` but the thing is `1/x` is NOT in `N`. So how clearly something isn't right.

This isn't the only case either as I've often run into trouble proving onto as after making `x` the subject the result doesn't seem to belong to the domain (i.e. `N`).

How do I correct this and what would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: If you need to prove that $A$ is infinite, it is enough to show that $F$ is one to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, you have already proved the function $F$ is injective.
Let's take *any* element $a$ from $A$, by definition there exists a positive integer $N$ such that  $N=\dfrac1a$, thus $a=\dfrac1N=F(N)$, we can conclude the function $F$ is onto.

Comment: That makes sense. My confusion arises from the fact that the functions domain is N, but we need to subsitute 1/n to get n. For example this link http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~booth/311-02/notes/notesonfns.html explains the process as changing subject and seeing if the result falls in the domain before substituting.

Comment: @Warrshrike I'm happy if it helped. You can accept my answer above if you want ;) (the button $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ on the left).